# How can i divide section of fullpage.js in 2 parts(divs) and enable **scrolling** only on one right (div) with using **Fullpage.js**?

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

Here is HTML, Div of webpage is working though! i need to add some more content on second div and make it enable scrolling when i do so.

```
<section class="vertical-scrolling" id="section">
<div id="abt">
      <div id="about" >
          <h3>about</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="abouttxt">
         content with scrolling
      </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here is CSS:

```
#about {
height: relative;
    float: left;
}
#abouttxt {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
 <div class="section">
        <div class="leftSide">
            <div class="box">Whatever</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSide">
            <div class="box">Whatever</div>
            <div class="box">Whatever</div>
            <div class="box">Whatever</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftSide{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.rightSide{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Then you have to use the option `normalScrollElements` of fullpage.js:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    normalScrollElements: '.rightSide'
});
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1393/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content, html, body {
height: 98%;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: it is not working in **Fullpage.Js** sections thanks tho!